# Why are date vaules displaying a trailing 'Z' when layers are published with Geoserver and a PostGIS data store?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, postgis-2.0, geotools

I have published various layers using Geoserver 2.2.x with a PostGIS 2.0.1 (PostgreSQL 9.1.x) data store. Fields that only have date values and not time/timestamp related values are stored as date. After publishing my layers as wfs/wms and opening the table in the browser date vlues are displaying with a trailing 'Z'.

**Is this a product of the geotools data store api that geoserver is using?**

I think the geotools data store api is throwing a blanket over the data reading date as datetime, timestamp etc and the 'z' gets displayed for zulu time. I could be totally off on my geotools assumption but in PostgreSQL 'z' represents zulu or utc.

**If the data source values are stored as date and have no time component why is there a trailing 'Z' in the date field?**

[image: Here multiple date values display with a trailing 'Z']

Comment: I think dates get converted to timestamps internally. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Date+Time+handling for some discussion

Answer (score 6):

It appears you were/are on the right track as the 'Z' is used for a timezone indicator, here is the source I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/833143/4095322) that best answers your question

> "Z" is kind of a unique case for DateTimes. The literal "Z" is actually part of the ISO 8601 datetime standard for UTC times. When "Z" (Zulu) is tacked on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC, so really the literal Z is part of the time.

Comment: But this doesn't really explain why the timezone indicator is used for dates that have no time component.

Comment: because with out a timezone you don't know what day it is - consider when a day starts in UTC+24 as compared to UTC-23

Answer (score 3):

Start your Goserver with this Java option:

```
-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true
```

It will tell Geotools to not modify date objects (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/factory/GeoTools.html#LOCAL_DATE_TIME_HANDLING).

You need to have at least version 15 of Geotools for this to work.