# GeoServer subtracts time difference to UTC from date stored in PostgreSQL

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, date

We have in our PostgreSQL database records that include a date, i.e. stored as data type **date** (yyyy-MM-dd). The data are published in Geoserver.
If we request the records from an OpenLayers application, GeoServer returns the date as yyyy-MM-dd**Z** but a day early, e.g. 2021-10-06 is returned as 2021-10-05Z. We are located in time zone GMT+2 so it appears that GeoServer subtracts the time difference and thus returns the wrong date.

The result is that the wrong date is shown in the application. This can be handled programmatically but the question really is why GeoServer is involving time zone for a date that's not stored with a time zone and if it's supposed to be like that? Is the date actually stored as a time stamp "under the hood"?

Comment: A day requires a timezone to be fully defined, GeoServer always uses GMT so this is the expected behaviour

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/why-are-date-vaules-displaying-a-trailing-z-when-layers-are-published-with-geo

Comment: All that you can get from ISO for free is https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html and there is this example `For example, September 27, 2012 is represented as 2012-09-27`. I have thought that timezone can only be used after time `2021-10-08T12:17:43Z`. Is `2021-10-05Z` really valid?

Comment: because with out a timezone you don't know what day it is - consider when a day starts in UTC+24 as compared to UTC-23

Comment: Yes, but my question is if ISO-8601 supports `2021-10-05Z`. It certainly does support `2021-10-05` even it is fuzzy. Perhaps exact dates can only be expressed as datetimeZ `2021-10-05T00:00Z`? Wikipedia article in not aware of dateZ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Comment: There is some discussion on this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761047/what-difference-between-the-date-time-datetime-and-timestamp-types. The user Booboo has an interesting take on it that I tend to agree with.